# How can I create a namespace with kustomize?

Tags: kustomize

I've a simple project that use kustomize like this:

```
base/
  namespace.yaml
  kustomization.yaml
  service.yaml
```

With `kustomization.yaml` is:

```
resources:
  - namespace.yaml
  - service.yaml
namespace: my_wanted_namespace
```

And `namespace.yaml` is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: default
```

The problem is that when I do: `kustomize build ./base`

I've this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: default
```

How can I have

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: my_wanted_namespace
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same problem to solve, it's such a needed feature IMO

Comment: Would you mind marking one of the answers as the correct one?

Comment: all of the answers have an issue with name prefix. the namespace is a fixed name but the prefix gets added to the namespace name which makes it different. So you can't seem to be able to use name prefix with namespaces

Answer (score 26):

If you want to create your namespace with kustomize, your kustomize file should look like this. It has to use the namespace.

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: my-wanted-namespace
resources:
- ./namespace.yml
```

And your namespace file should be a normal namespace deployment like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: my-wanted-namespace
```

Comment: Let’s say it’s the base and in an overlay I want to use another namespace, I have to recreate an other namespace.yml file with the wanted namespace. Feel kind like ugly for me. I wish I could at least use variables for this purpose but not...

Comment: The answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71150557/844614) shoes that the namespace name in `namespace.yml` doesn't actually matter, and that seems to be the case for me.

Comment: @Djabx for something like that you should take a look at ytt from cravel or helm.
The other possibility is as you stated creating a namespace file.

Answer (score 14):

You can remove the namespace resource from `base` and only include it in the overlay. E.g:

`overlay/kustomization.yaml`

```yaml
namespace: my_wanted_namespace
bases:
- ../base
resources:
- namespace.yaml
```

`overlay/namespace.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: my_wanted_namespace
```

It is important that the `namespace` property in the `kustomization.yaml` file matches the name in the `namespace.yaml` resource and that `base/service.yaml` **doesn't** set the `namespace` property.

---

EDIT: original response below

> As an alternative to Hadrien's answer, JSON Patch also worked for me:
>
> ```
> namespace: my-wanted-namespace
> patchesJSON6902:
> - target:
>     version: v1
>     kind: Namespace
>     name: base-namespace
>   patch: |-
>     - op: replace
>       path: /metadata/name
>       value: my-wanted-namespace
> ```
>
> The key of this method is transforming the base `Namespace` name to
> match exactly the `namespace` key in the overlay `kustomization.yaml`
> file.

Comment: This technique based on `patchesJSON6902:` worked perfectly for me using `kustomize-v3.8.4`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8):

Old post, but the above answers are more complicated than needed.

In `kustomization.yaml`

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namespace: my-desired-namespace
resources:
- namespace.yaml
```

and in `namespace.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: intentionally.broken.namespace
```

Realistically, I have a folder elsewhere with a kustomization and the dummy namespace that I can include as a resource from any of my kustomizations. The kustomization will replace the Namespace name with the namespace transformer, and create it.

Comment: The copy-past of the answer given by Azak https://stackoverflow.com/a/57640208/1531661

Comment: There’s a subtle difference. That answer implies that the “namespace:” field needs to match the name of the namespace. So if you use overlays to create 10 namespaces, you’d need 10 namespace files. 

I just called out that the names don’t need to match, so you can have one namespace.yaml that you include as a resource from all your namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Old post but I have another example to include for future wanderers.

In your base, you can have Namespace declared using namespace.yaml. I.e. that will be a default value.

```
base/
  namespace.yaml
  kustomization.yaml
  ...
```

Example `base/namespace.yaml` contents:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: default
```

In your `overlay/kustomization.yaml` use [PatchTransformer](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/builtins/#_patchtransformer_) to update value of the default namespace without creating namespace resource in each overlay directory.

Example `overlay/kustomization.yaml` contents:

```yaml
namespace: my-wanted-namespace

resources:
- ../base

patches:
- target:
    kind: Namespace
    name: default
  patch: |-
    - op: replace
      path: /metadata/name
      value: my-wanted-namespace
```

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, the simplest answer is this:

#### in base

- do NOT include a namespace.yaml
- do NOT add namespace to your resources

#### in overlay or environment

- add a namespace.yaml if you need to create a dedicated namespace
- add the `namespace: my-name` to the kustomization.yaml in your overlay

#### folder structure

so the structure is like this

```
base/
 - service.yaml
 - ...
 - kustomization.yaml
overlays/
 - some-overlay/
   - namespace.yaml # (optional) can be defined here
   - kustomization.yaml
environments/
 - environment-1/
   - namespace.yaml # or define it here
   - kustomization.yaml # with namespace: my-name
```

you can see in `kustomize build .` output of the environment that all resources are correctly scoped to the namespace.

for reference:

```
# kustomization.yaml in environment
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namespace: my-namespace

bases:
- ../base/

resources:
- namespace.yaml
```

See documentation here: https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/namespace/

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to create a namespace on the fly and use it for the other resources Kustomize will customize, you can use this trick:

```
namespace=${1:-"my-namespace-meaning"}

rm -rf ./base
mkdir ./base

cat <<EOF > ./base/namespace.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: suffix
EOF

cat <<EOF > ./base/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: docker-registry
  labels:
    name: docker-registry
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5001
      targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    name: docker-registry
  type: ClusterIP
EOF

cat <<EOF > ./base/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: docker-registry
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: docker-registry
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: docker-registry
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: docker-registry
          image: registry
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 200Mi
              cpu: 300m
            requests:
              memory: 100Mi
              cpu: 100m
EOF

cat <<EOF > ./kustomization.yaml
namePrefix: "${namespace}-"

namespace: "${namespace}-suffix"

resources:
- base/deployment.yaml
- base/namespace.yaml
- base/service.yaml
EOF

kubectl kustomize ./
```

Running this script will output:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: my-namespace-meaning-suffix
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: docker-registry
  name: my-namespace-meaning-docker-registry
  namespace: my-namespace-meaning-suffix
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5001
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    name: docker-registry
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-namespace-meaning-docker-registry
  namespace: my-namespace-meaning-suffix
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: docker-registry
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: docker-registry
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: registry
        name: docker-registry
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 300m
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
```

The idea is to first use the `namePrefix` keyword ([doc here](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/nameprefix/)) in order to deterministically define the value of the namespace after customization. Then this customized namespace can be used for each other resource thanks to the `namespace` keyword ([doc here](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/namespace/)).

Comment: Unfortunately, doc links are out-dated.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Josiah, I updated the links, I hope they will help.

Comment: I did a slight change to your kustomization file and it worked great for me! the trick is to match the expected namespace with either a suffix or a prefix.

Comment: @MartínColl thank you for your feedback! Would you like to share this slight change :p?

Comment: NP, just posted it!

Comment: Thank you very much!