# Kustomize: How to set metadata.name of a resource we need to patch

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

How to set `metadata.name` from a variable value, when kustomizing a base ressource.

For creating for example a namespace, but we don’t know its name in advance but need to “kustomize” like adding commonLabels etc to it?

The way Kustomize operates is that you kustomize a base resource already defined with an apiVersion, kind, metadata.name. So I haven't found a way to afterwards set the final resource name.

Comment: I found my answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57594001/how-can-i-create-a-namespace-with-kustomize

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly there are few options depending on your needs:

1. Use [Helm](https://helm.sh/)

> Helm helps you manage Kubernetes applications — Helm Charts help you
>   define, install, and upgrade even the most complex Kubernetes
>   application.

2. Use [PodPreset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/podpreset/)

> You can use a `PodPreset` object to inject information like secrets,
>   volume mounts, and environment variables etc into pods at creation
>   time.

3. Use [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

> `ConfigMaps` allow you to decouple configuration artifacts from image
>   content to keep containerized applications portable.

4. You can modify your deployments dynamically and than run `kubectl replace -f FILE` command. Or use `kubectl edit DEPLOYMENT` command in order to automatically applly the changes.

Please let me know if that helped.